# Linux Media Player

Tags: linux, networking, streaming, media-player, embedded

I have a SYABAS-based NAS Multimedia Server, which is connected via LAN to a PC running embedded Linux.

I can get a list of content on the NAS device, but when I press play, it does not play, but displays the text path of the media file itself.

In short it does not play streamed content, whereas the same content I am able to play using Windows based Internet Explorer.

I meed a media player to work with embedded linux....

Comment: What are you currently trying to use to play the media file?

Answer (score 1):

I believe it would be because you don't have appropriate plugins installed in your browser to play the content.  If you are using Firefox, you might want to look at the [VLC Mozilla plugin](http://www.videolan.org/doc/vlc-user-guide/en/ch07.html) which you can probably download through your distro.